# CV review badge description incorrect

Tags: discussion, badges

On the [close votes stats page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) is a description of the three badges one could earn by reviewing close votes. By the logic of the descriptions, one should get [steward](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steward) at 1251 reviews, not at 1000.

[image]

Comment: someone's eager to be a steward. :P

Comment: who would that be? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it can be taken as you say and it could be consfusing, but... You're reading them as a cumulative sequence. As in "review one, then review *another 250*, then review *another 1000*". But they're actually completely separate statements, each taken from your current review stats, so you do *currently* need to review "one item", "250 more" and "1000 more" for each badge. They're completely separate, not cumulative.

So, it's (potentially) confusing... but each is technically correct.

Comment: Ill keep the [tag:bug] on it for now until someone descends from the Pantheon to tell us they ain't gonna fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

*This is by all of the review pages* (correct me if I'm wrong)

So while in [First Posts Review](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts), I noticed that it *is* in fact **Correct/Accurate**.

I've reviewed 50, so far. and need to review 200 *more* in order to receive the [<kbd>O Reviewer</kbd>](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/reviewer) and 950 *more* in order to receive the [<kbd>♦ Steward</kbd>](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/86/steward)

The reason that it's different by you Pie, is that you haven't done any close voting yet (almost there though)

**IMO:** While this method for displaying it, can be a bit confusing. it is not inaccurate in any way.

---

[image: WELZ's Review Badge]

---

On a side note...

I would suggest it said something more like:

> [<kbd>♦ Steward</kbd>](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/86/steward) Review 1000 posts, *950 more to go*

P.S. Maybe we should migrate it to [Meta.SE](http://s.tk/meta) as this is across all exchanges and probably causes confusion *everywhere*.